# BCD Counter C++

Tags: c++, graphics, binary, decoder

I have an assignment to build a 7 segment BCD counter. The idea is to generate binary numbers 000, 001, etc all the way up to 9, and then feed them into a BCD decoder and the display will be a 7 segment display that counts 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, etc. I know this is typically done with an FPGA board, but since we're distance learning the task is to perform this using simple C++ graphics. I had a previous project where the user would input a binary number and the display would display the number in the seven seg, so I built off of that. However, I'm getting a floating point fault and the program crashes and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "dec2baser.cpp"


using namespace std;

deque<char>textQ;   // holding a message
int bits[100];      // holding bits entered
bool enter = false;

class Point {
public:
  float v[2];
  Point() { v[0] = v[1] = 0;}
  Point( float x0, float y0 ){ 
    v[0] = x0;
    v[1] = y0;
  }
  Point( float v0[] ){
    v[0] = v0[0];
    v[1] = v0[1];
  }
  void move ( float dx, float dy )
  {
    v[0] += dx;
    v[1] += dy;
  }
};


void aLine ( Point p0, Point p1, int thick ) //modifies width based on what segment is activated 
{
  if ( !thick )     // thin line
    glLineWidth ( 1 );
  else             // thick line
    glLineWidth ( 4 );
  glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glVertex2fv ( p0.v );
    glVertex2fv ( p1.v );
      glEnd();

}

void text ( char *s )
{
  char *p;

  for ( p = s; *p; p++ )
     glutBitmapCharacter (  GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, (int) *p );
//    glutBitmapCharacter ( GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, *p );
}




/*bool getBits()
{
  char s[400], s1[400];
  float x = -9, y = 9;
  int i, n;
  static bool first = true;
  enter = false;
  glColor3f (0, 0, 0);
  strcpy ( s, "Press'q' to quit: \n");
  if ( first ) {
     glRasterPos2f ( x, y );
     text ( s );
     first = false;
     return enter;
  }
  n = strlen( s );
  i = 0;
  deque <char> :: iterator it;
  for (it = textQ.begin(); it != textQ.end(); ++it) {
    if ( i > 100 ) break;
    s[i+n] = s1[i] = *it;
    if ( s1[i] == '\r' ) {
      s[i+n] = s1[i]  = 0;
      enter = true;
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }
  s[i+n] = 0;
 s1[i] = 0;
  glRasterPos2f ( x, y );
  text ( s );
  if ( enter ) {
    glRasterPos2f ( 0, 0 );
    text ( s1 );
    i = 0;
    while ( s1[i] != 0 ) {
      bits[i] = s1[i] - '0';
      i++;
    }
    bits[i] = -1;  //signals end of bits
    textQ.erase(textQ.begin(), textQ.end() );
  }

  return enter;
}

void printBits()
{
   int i = 0;
   while ( bits[i] != -1 )
      cout << bits[i++];
   cout << endl;
}*/

void drawLines()
{
  Point p0, p1;
  p0 = Point ( -2, 2);
  p1 = Point ( 4,  2 );
  aLine ( p0, p1, 0 );   // thin horizontal

  p0.move ( 0, -1 );
  p1.move ( 0, -1 );
  aLine ( p0, p1, 1 );   // thick horizontal

  p0 = Point ( -2, 0);
  p1 = Point ( -2, -5 );
  aLine ( p0, p1, 0 );   // thin vertical 

  p0.move ( 4, 0 );
  p1.move ( 4, 0 );
  aLine ( p0, p1, 1 );   // thick vertical
}

void display()
{
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );       //clear screen
  //if ( getBits() ) commented out because user is not inputing any bits

  char res[100];
 
  unsigned int microsecond = 1000000;

      for ( int  i = 0; i < 9; i ++ ) 
      {
            binaryGen(res, i, 2);
        drawLines();
            usleep( 1 * microsecond); //wait for 1 second
      }

  glFlush();                            //send all output to screen
}

void keyboard ( unsigned char key, int mousex, int mousey )
{
   switch ( key ) {
     case 27:       // escape
     case 'q':
       exit ( -1 );

   }
   if ( key == '\b' )  // back space
       textQ.pop_back();
     else
       textQ.push_back( key );
    glutPostRedisplay();

     return;
}
```

As you can see I have the getbits function commented out because that was for my previous project where the user would input the values and the program would display that value. That's the drawing source code, now here's my main source code.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//function call protos
void init(void);
void display (void);
void keyboard ( unsigned char key, int mousex, int mousey );

//modified to initialize our display
void init(void)
{
  const char *version;

  glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );   //get white background color
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );        //set drawing color
  glPointSize( 4.0 );                   //a dot is 4x4
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D( -10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0 );
}

/*  Main Loop
 *  Open window with initial window size, title bar, 
 *  RGBA drawLines mode, depth buffer.
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  glutInit(&argc, argv);        //initialize toolkit
  glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );        //set drawLines mode
  glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);         //set window size on screen
  glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 150 );   //set window position on screen
  glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);            //open screen widow
  init();
  glutKeyboardFunc ( keyboard );
  glutDisplayFunc (display );           //points to drawLines function
  glutMainLoop();                       //go into perpetual loop
  return 0;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated, I'm relatively new to coding so if there's any obvious errors you see let me know. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?